# Integrate $\frac{x^2- 4}{x^4 + 24x^2 +16}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

> $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^2- 4}{x^4 + 24x^2 +16} dx$

Attempt:

I have tried splitting and solving it.

I have also tried completing the square but these methods aren't helping here.

Dividing numerator and denominator by $x^2$ didn't help too.

How do I go about solving it?

Answer (score 6):

Use partial fraction decomposition:$$\frac{x-4}{x^2+24x+16}=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2\left(x+12+8\sqrt2\right)}+\frac{1-\sqrt2}{2\left(x+12-8\sqrt2\right)}$$and therefore$$\frac{x^2-4}{x^4+24x^2+16}=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2\left(x^2+12+8\sqrt2\right)}+\frac{1-\sqrt2}{2\left(x^2+12-8\sqrt2\right)}.$$

Answer (score 4):

The denominator is a sum of squares
$$
(4x)^2 + (x^2+4)^2 = x^4+24x^2+16
$$
Using that to suggest a trig substitution, we get
$$
\int\dfrac{x^2- 4}{x^4 + 24x^2 +16} \;dx = -\frac{1}{4}\arctan\left(\frac{4x}{x^2+4}\right) + C
$$

(Of course, the problem is rigged.  If we had some other numerator, this method would probably not help.)

Comment: which trig substitution?

Comment: If we have a sum of squares $A^2+B^2$, we should try any of the trig substitutions $\cos^2\theta = A^2/(A^2+B^2), \sin^2\theta = B^2/(A^2+B^2), \tan\theta = B/A$. So try $\tan\theta = (4x)/(x^2+4)$ here.

Comment: I was unaware of that.Do you mind including the method in your answer?

Comment: Google "trig substitution" and find out all about this very useful method.  Or just look in your calculus textbook.

Answer (score 0):

**A REMARK**

Because of $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{x^2+4}{4x}\right)=\dfrac{x^2-4}{4x^2}$ we can deduce
$$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^2- 4}{x^4 + 24x^2 +16} dx=\displaystyle 4\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\dfrac{x^2+4}{4x}\right)\tag 1$$ But similarly we can get
$$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^2- 4}{x^4 + 24x^2 +16} dx=-\frac14\displaystyle\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\dfrac{4x}{x^2+4}\right)\tag 2$$
So, despite the apparent mistake one can give the answer $(1)$ instead of GEdgar's answer $(2)$.

In other words $$\displaystyle 4\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\dfrac{x^2+4}{4x}\right)=-\frac14\displaystyle\int \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan\dfrac{4x}{x^2+4}\right)$$

Comment: Who is the little man.........? The next time "correct" $2 + 2 = 4$ with $2 + 2 = 17$